# How to select columns from two tables, and order by one of them?

Tags: mysql

i want to do one thing on my mysql DB.

I have two tables:

first_table:

```
| article          | longtext             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| article_id       | int(11)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Second_table:

```
| id    | int(11)  |
| name  | longtext | 
| commit_date  | date |
```

When first_table.article_id = second_table.id, then article = name.

I want to select article and article_id from first table and sort them by commit_date (correct for every record), which is in the second table.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following query, should do what you want :

```
SELECT article, article_id
FROM first_table f
JOIN Second_table s ON f.article_id = s.id AND f.article = s.name
ORDER BY s.commit_date
```